# Running a program in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Each time I try to run a new program, an old program 'client.java' is run by eclipse. How do I change this setting? How do we tell eclipse which program to run? I tried using the arrow beside run button but it dosen't list out my new program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the default behavior by going to Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching and in the 'Launch Operation' section, select the radio button for **Launch the selected resource or active editor** and then select **Launch the associated project** underneath.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Right Click To the class -> Run As-> JAVA Application

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all make sure that your program has a main class.

Then click in the black button next to the run button -> Run As-> JAVA Application.

If this doesn work make sure you have all this properly set up.

[Run Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YezjQ.png)